# Is there a way to provide a response to the menu function before prompted?

Tags: r, function

I am using a function in a loop, but the creator of the function designed it to prompt the user for input. I was wondering if there was a way to preemptively provide the input so I don't have to stop the loop and manually type in my response each time.

Specifically, the menu function is used:

```
menu(c("yes", "no", "maybe"), title="Choose one of the options")
```

Is there a way I can input "yes" or "1" automatically rather than type it out each time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Easiest solution might be to create your own version of the function that takes an argument instead of the `menu` input.

Comment: You could redefine menu in the global environment, qutie the hack, not beautiful, but should work. `menu <- function(...) 1`

Comment: Just to follow up on this in case anyone needed a solution. The solutions I found were to modify the function. This can be done using trace:

`trace(functionName, edit=TRUE)`

Alternatively, one could make a modified version of the function (functionName2) and use assignInNamespace:

`tmpfun <- get("functionName", envir = asNamespace("packageName"))
environment(functionName2) <- environment(tmpfun)
attributes(functionName2) <- attributes(tmpfun)
assignInNamespace("functionName", functionName, ns="packageName")`